# How to use a 3TB (3000GB) USB backup HDD (Hard Disk Drive) On Windows XP 32 bit?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, external-hard-drive

.
How to use a 3TB (3000GB) USB backup HDD (Hard Disk Drive) On Windows XP 32 bit?

Before I buy a 3TB+ USB drive...
Can I format this 3TB USB drive with Window 7 as 2 partitions?
2TB + 1TB = 3TB

And then move 3TB USB drive from Win7 to WinXP.

Will Windows XP 32-bit see this 3TB USB drive as 2 partitions?
2TB + 1TB = 3TB
Can Windows XP 32-bit use all the 3TB drive in 2 partitions?

Said differently:
This 3TB USB drive is not for the OS (Operating System).
This 3TB USB drive is for data backup on a WinXP 32-bit computer.

Ideally, this 3TB USB drive will have only Win7 formatting of: 
2TB + 1TB = 3TB

Ideally, this 3TB USB drive will have no third party software to do 
advanced partitioning scheme like GUID Partition Table (GPT) which 
can support 3TB+ volumes in 1 partition.

September 2017, here is one sample of a drive that is on sale and is even larger than 3TB:
$99.99 for Seagate Backup Plus 4TB USB 3.0 External Desktop Hard Drive (STFM4000100)
http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/seagate-backup-plus-4tb-usb-3-0-external-desktop-hard-drive-stfm4000100/10651319.aspx?

Question:
How to use a 3TB (3000GB) USB backup HDD (Hard Disk Drive) On Windows XP 32 bit?

--

Comment: Here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2581408/windows-support-for-hard-disks-that-are-larger-than-2-tb and https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/choosing_between_ntfs_fat_and_fat32.mspx?mfr=true both seems to suggest yes, this is possible so have a read.

Comment: You will be able to use 2TB maybe 2.2TB and that is it.  The rest will simply be inaccessible.  You need GPT and windows XP has no support for that.